# what does the error mean:"unexpected_delivery_and_no_default_consumer"

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I use rabbitmq-erlang-client rabbitmq_2.7.0 in my production env. Recently, I have found some error as "unexpected_delivery_and_no_default_consumer" in my server app log.

```
2016-08-26 15:25:00.465 [error]  CRASH REPORT Process  with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {unexpected_delivery_and_no_default_consumer,{gen_server2,call,[,{consumer_call,{'basic.deliver',>,15804,false,>,>},{amqp_msg,{'P_basic',undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined},>}},infinity]}} in gen_server:terminate/7 line 826
```

rabbitmq consumer res:

[rabbitmqctl list_consumers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwFiq.png)

Why "amq.ctag-2I715Fu1Q2m9AHgrhlN1Og" is not in the consumers tags?

PS:
1. I do not use the method 'basic.cancel'.
2. I config the msg as "no_ack = true"